# how to delegate this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var selValues = {};
selValues['234'] = $('#asd').val();
selValues['343'] = function () { var el = ''; $('#asd input[@type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() { el += $(this).val() + '|'; }); return el; } };
```

here's the explanation:

im creating a key-value array where it extracts different values from DOM objects. The last array that you see in the example actually tries to extract checked items in a checkbox list. I tried to delegate the loop and return a delimited string of all checked values, but it's not working.

Comment: i tried using the function() in placing values but its not working.

Comment: You really(EDIT: really, really, really) should explain, `exactly` what you are trying to achieve in you question.

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve Event "delegation"?

Comment: @pramodc84, hi. do you notice anything wrong with my code that will cause it to not to work? i also tried using delegate() {} but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `mapping` is probably a better solution here:

```
var el = $('#asd input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join('|');
```

Comment: If that's an equivalent of what they're trying to do, I like this approach way better :)

Comment: my own mistakes, accidentally added an apostrophe between the .get() and .join('|').

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the problem you are running up against is that you are merely storing a function in `selValues['343']`, not evaluating it.

You could try `selValues['343'] = function () { var el = ''; $('#asd input[@type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() { el += $(this).val() + '|'; }); return el; } }();` (notice the parentheses at the end) which should evaluate your function and store the result in `selValues['343']`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HM4zD/

Comment: cool link. if you do a alert(JSON.stringify(selValues));, the result to speak otherwise.